# Trouble w/ Peter's Data Entry Suite ("DES") Validation. Instruction are not working with C# ASP,

Tags: c#, asp.net, peterblum

The following control was in the code.
Below .aspx will the be the start of the .aspx.cs that starts out Page_Load.
It is allowing the date to be changed in the variable, but the interface doesn't show an error.

I am using the following tutorial.
http://learningdes.peterblum.com/Validation/Validators/Controls/RangeValidator.aspx

```
 <des:MonthYearTextBox ID="dtbEndMonth" runat="server" Font-Size="8" AutoHint="false">
 </des:MonthYearTextBox>
 <des:DateTextBox ID="dtbEndDate" runat="server" AutoHint="false" CssClass="DateTextBox" 
      PopupCalendar-ToggleImageAlign="bottom" PopupCalendar-
      ToggleImageUrl="~/Images/calendar_view_month.png">
 </des:DateTextBox>
 <des:DataTypeCheckValidator ID="DataTypeCheckValidator2" 
      ControlIDToEvaluate="dtbEndDate"
      runat="server" DataType="Date" 
     ErrorMessage="The correct format for this date is MM/dd/yyyy"
     Group="DateRange">
      <ErrorFormatterContainer>
           <des:TooltipImageErrorFormatter ImageURL="~/Images/error_small.png"
            Display="Dynamic" />
      </ErrorFormatterContainer>
      </des:DataTypeCheckValidator>
          <des:RangeValidator ID="EndDateRangeValidator" runat="server" 
                ControlIDToEvaluate="dtbEndDate"
                ErrorMessage="End Date must be between 2005 and {Maximum}" 
                Minimum="01/01/2005"
                Group="DateRange">
       <ErrorFormatterContainer>
                 <des:TooltipImageErrorFormatter ImageURL="~/Images/error_small.png" 
                      Display="Dynamic" />
             </ErrorFormatterContainer>
             <HiliteFields>
                  <des:ControlConnection ControlID="dtbEndDate" />
             </HiliteFields>
       </des:RangeValidator>
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartDateRangeValidator.MaximumAsNative = DateTime.Today;
    EndDateRangeValidator.MaximumAsNative = DateTime.Today;
```

...

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: In the example Peter shows the error messages in the click event, with this line: `if (PeterBlum.DES.Globals.WebFormDirector.IsValid)`

Comment: There is no error in the code, but the maximum date is not saying the future date is invalid.  It still shows the minimum date is invalid

Comment: The following code is for server side validation.  I am making the adjustments in the client side code.  I will need to figure out why this check is not in the code.
`   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (PeterBlum.DES.Globals.WebFormDirector.IsValid)
      {
         // save your data here
      }
   }`

Comment: Since PeterBlum.DES.Globals.WebFormDirector.IsValid was not checked on the form I added it, but WebFormDirector didn't show up in Globals.